# How can I reduce media playback volume while on a call?

Tags: iphone, sound-volume, call

How do I mute my media while on a phone call? I’d like to watch videos while I’m on the phone, but they are so loud, I can’t hear the person on the other end, and if I simply turn the volume down, it also turns the call volume down. Please help